# Trouble with an Odd Integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Here is a Integral I am having some trouble with

$$\int_0^\pi \sin^2\Big(x^2-\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}\Big)dx$$
A while back I integrated $\int_0^\pi \sin^2\Big(x-\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}\Big)dx$ and found it was equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$; so I tried  to substitute $u=x^2$  that got me somewhere, but I am having quite a bit of trouble. Any help would be much appreciate

Comment: the first one, it is pretty clear @xpaul

Comment: have you tried with $u=x^2 - \sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}$?

Comment: @Exodd hmm Nope, gonna go try that! Could you post an answer showing your solution so I can check my work? Thanks!

Comment: You succeeded to prove $$ \int_0^\pi \sin^2\Big(x-\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}\Big)dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Then you want to know the value of 
$$\int_0^\pi \sin^2\Big(x^\color{red}{2}-\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}\Big)dx$$
right?

Comment: @NN2 Yes! Thanks!

Comment: @SamuelMorrison According to WolframAlpha, there is no analytical solution.

Comment: Can you explain how you found the solution to the first integral, the one without the square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first prove this statement:

$$\int_0^\pi \sin^2\Big(x-\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}\Big)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Actually, we can compute a more general integral:

$$I(2n)=\int_0^\pi \sin^{2n}\Big(x-\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}\Big)dx$$

$$n=0,1,2,...$$

Let's split this integral into two:

$$I_1(2n)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} \sin^{2n}\Big(\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}-x\Big)dx$$

$$I_2(2n)=\int_\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}^\pi \sin^{2n}\Big(x-\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}\Big)dx$$

$$I(2n)=I_1(2n)+I_2(2n)$$

A bound of integration $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$ is a positive solution of the equation:

$$x-\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}=0$$

Now, make a change of variable in the integrals:

$$\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}-x=t$$ for $I_1(2n)$

and

$$x-\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}=t$$ for $I_2(2n)$

After the elementary transformations, we reach the classical integral:

$$I(2n)=\int_0^\pi \sin^{2n}t \;dt=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2}\pi$$

Now, what about

$$I=\int_0^\pi \sin^2\Big(\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}-x^2\Big)dx$$

The same method as the previous one is not suitable because we need to calculate integrals like

$$\int \sin x^2\;dx$$

$$\int \cos x^2\;dx$$

Below is a physicist's approach to get an approximate analytical solution.

The only way to achieve a such result is to linearize the argument of the **sine** function.
I use the simplest linear approximation

$$\sqrt{\pi^2-x^2}-x^2\approx \pi-(1+\pi)x$$

$$0\leqslant x \leqslant\pi$$

Result

$$I_{approx}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\sin(2\pi^2)}{4(1+\pi)}=1.52...$$

Exact value of the integral is $1.36...$ The approximation error is about $0.16$

For a physicist this is quite a satisfactory result.